# Query new column in joined table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to solve the DataLemur problem [here](https://datalemur.com/questions/sql-page-with-no-likes).

When I run my query to only take those matches from the left table I'm left with a table with a set of new columns. Now I want to query one of those new columns to identify those rows that are NULL.

I don't understand how to query this new joined table as it doesn't have a name. I've looked at other examples and am confused how they work.

My query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM pages p
LEFT JOIN page_likes pl ON p.page_id = pl.page_id
```

Current output from my query:

| page_id | page_name | user_id | page_id | liked_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20001 | SQL Solutions | 111 | 20001 | 04/08/2022 00:00:00 |
| 20045 | Brain Exercises | 121 | 20045 | 03/12/2022 00:00:00 |
| 20001 | SQL Solutions | 156 | 20001 | 07/25/2022 00:00:00 |
| 20045 | Brain Exercises | 255 | 20045 | 07/19/2022 00:00:00 |
| 20001 | SQL Solutions | 125 | 20001 | 07/19/2022 00:00:00 |
| 31111 | Postgres Crash Course | 144 | 31111 | 06/21/2022 00:00:00 |
| 31111 | Postgres Crash Course | 125 | 31111 | 07/04/2022 00:00:00 |
| 32728 | Break the thread | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 20701 | Tips for Data Analysts | NULL | NULL | NULL |

The way I've thought about solving this is to put the join in a CTE and alias that CTE and then call the column. But I'm not sure that is the right solution. What is the alias of the new table and how can I call the "liked_date" column and check if it's NULL?

Comment: *"I don't understand how to query this new joined table as it doesn't have a name"* This doesn't make sense; every object and column (within an object) has a name. It's impossible to create one without one. `CREATE TABLE [] ("" int);` would generate an error.

Comment: All you need is add a WHERE clause to your query: `WHERE pl.liked_date IS NULL`.

Comment: *"What is the alias of the new table"* `pl`? You define the alias in your query: `LEFT JOIN page_likes pl` do you not understand what the SQL you have does?

Comment: I'm confused, but I've done a left join and that is the p table. "pl" isn't in the picture anymore? Plus this new table is no longer "p"

Comment: `SELECT * FROM pages p
LEFT JOIN page_likes pl on p.page_id = pl.page_id` is in the "picture", you `LEFT JOIN` to it. Why do you think you *can't* reference that object in the `WHERE`/`SELECT`?

Comment: I thought I understood it, until you've added a new dimension of awareness. Back to basics it is then for me

Comment: I thought a new table is created by joining "p" and "pl", but this new table doesn't have an alias. So I was left confused. It appears the "p" and "pl" aliases are preserved against each column in this new joined table if I read your response right

Comment: There is no "new" table... Only a resultset that is the list of rows resulting for the execution of your query. Like in any other algrebrae, the result of an operation is not a new object...  SQL is based on relational algebrae invented by ted Codd in the early 70th...

Comment: @Dan It might save you some headache in the future. Use the word "table" to refer actual database objects, so in SQL Server things that exist in Information_Schema.Tables . For query results, the term "result" or "result set" would avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple, here you go:

```
SELECT * 
FROM pages p
LEFT JOIN page_likes pl ON p.page_id = pl.page_id 
WHERE liked_date IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the other answer, all you have to do is add a WHERE clause; perhaps you are wondering why this works. You have access to all columns of both tables entering the join, regardless of whether or not they are included in the result (even though you've specified *all* of them via the asterisk). Note that liked_date does not need to be qualified by an alias because the column name only exists in one table (there is no ambiguity); you have to qualify page_id with an alias because both tables have a column of the same name.